# Issue with my app engine (i.e. meya.appspot.com)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I uploaded my app through the google app engine, but  when I navigate to meyapay.appspot.com I get this error:

"Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds."

I have checked the log file and this is what I got:

INFO 2014-06-20 19:23:34,904 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: localhost:8000 ERROR 2014-06-20 19:10:28,390 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\appinventordb\main.py", line 18, in  from django.utils import simplejson as json ImportError: No module named django.utils INFO 2014-06-20 20:10:28,427 module.py:639] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500

I am pretty much confused right now and in need of help

Comment: stuff you want to go up with your app (like imports) has to be in the same directory as your app.yaml so when deployed it can be imported. Also the log file error you have shown could not possibly have come from the deployed version. You also do not say if your app works locally or not.

Comment: also do you have the import for django in your app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
application: meyapay
version: 1 
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "latest"

handlers: 
- url: /images 
  static_dir: images

- url: .* 
  script: main.app
```

Comment: Tried this and this is what I got: "appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\appinventordb\app.yaml: threadsafe must be present and set to either "yes" or "no"
  in "C:\Users\expensivestephen\Desktop\appinventordb\app.yaml", line 15, column 19.
2014-06-21 00:22:52 (Process exited with code 2)"

Comment: ok, do what the error log says add threadsafe: true to the app.yaml